Improve Dapper query with more than 7 joins mapping on .NET 8
I'm using Dapper to execute a stored procedure that joins multiple tables and maps the results to various related objects. The code works, but I find it a bit cumbersome and I'm not sure if I'm using the mapping correctly.
Here's the current implementation:
MainEntity? result = null;

await connection.QueryAsync( 
        sql: StoredProceduresConstants.GetDataById, 
        types: new[] { typeof(MainEntity), typeof(Setting), typeof(Catalog), typeof(Domain), typeof(User), typeof(User), typeof(EntityLanguage), typeof(Language) }, 
        
        map: (objects) => { 
           result ??= objects[0] as MainEntity ?? new();

           if (objects[1] is not null) 
               result.Settings.Add(objects[1] as Setting);

           if (objects[2] is not null) 
               result.Catalogs.Add(objects[2] as Catalog);

           if (objects[3] is not null) 
               result.Domains.Add(objects[3] as Domain);

           result.CreatedBy = objects[4] as User;
           result.ModifiedBy = objects[5] as User;

           if (objects[7] is not null && objects[6] is not null)
           {
               var entityLanguage = objects[6] as EntityLanguage;
               entityLanguage.Language = objects[7] as Language;
               result.EntityLanguages.Add(entityLanguage);
           }

           return result;
        },
        splitOn: "Id",
        param: parameters,
        commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

Any suggestions or examples would be greatly appreciated, is hard to find examples of this type of queries. Thanks!
I tried the code shown above and it's working as supposed to but I'm not sure if I'm using the tool the right way.

You have cartesian join explosion. Consider using separate queries in a single batch, and connection.QueryMultipleAsync.
